# Customized clickable object(button) IOS - Objective C (Xcode5)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to create a kind of clickable object, could be a button.
The graphic should be rectangle with text in the middle. The rectangle should be clickable, like a button. It should have four lables on the corners which should be able to hold integers. When clicking on those "labels", i need another action to be done, like again a button.

How on earth should i start with this?

Comment: Can you add some sort of diagram or make something in paint?  I'm a little confused

Comment: I Would if i could :-( But lacking rep on this site..
Dunno if this is ok, but here you can get an idea of what i want to create. The four "labels" should also be clickable. http://flic.kr/ps/2BFPNU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a UIView subclass with five buttons (if they can be tapped, they should be buttons not labels)

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *middleButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *topLeftButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *topRightButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *bottomLeftButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *bottomRightButton;
```

You will also need to connect an IBAction to tell when the buttons are tapped.

```
[self.middleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(middleButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)middleButtonTapped
{
    //This method is called when the middle button is tapped
}
```

You can also create IBAction and hook the buttons up in the storyboard/xib

```
- (IBAction)middleButtonTapped
{

    //This method is called when the middle button is tapped
}
```

Comment: I have done the above but how will i be able to create the graphic. Like in the storyboard.

Comment: I have done the above but how will I be able to create the graphic. Like in the storyboard.
And also how can I control where the new instance of the view will be positioned when I create it.